# Django 2 - Login Authentication PROBLEM: MultiValueDictKeyError for username

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to implement for the first time the authentication for Django.

I am creating the login part following the official guide of Django 2. However I am having this problem:

```
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError Exception Value: 'username'
```

I created an app called "accounts". Inside of it, I have the following:

In accounts/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout    
def login(request):
      username = request.POST['username']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None:
        return redirect('home')
      else:
        return render(request, "accounts/login.html")
```

In templates/accounts.html:

```
{% extends 'mysite/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
Username:
<br>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br>
Password:
<br />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br>
<br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

In urls.py (of my app "accounts" not of the project):

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup/", views.signup, name="signup"),
    path("login/", views.login, name="login"),
    path("logout/", views.logout, name="logout"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    ...
```

You get the error because your view *always* tries to get `username` from the POST data. However, for the initial GET request, `request.POST` will be empty.

You shouldn't try to write your own login view like this. Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). You should use them.

Comment: I followed the guide you posted, many thanks. I have just a minor issue, do you know why it redirects me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/" once I click login? I don't understand why it does it since: 1) "profile" is not in the standard Django authentication 2) I specified "return redirect('home')" in the "login views"

Comment: Use the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting to control where Django redirects users to after login.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the request method before doing authentication like following

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout    
def login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      return redirect('home')
    else:
      return render(request, "accounts/login.html")
  else:
    return render(request, "accounts/login.html")
```